# Enable drag and drop of nodes only within the same parent

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs3, treenode

I have an ExtJs (3.4) tree with multiple nodes, each nodes have multiples children. I would like to allow drag and drop within each parents and I want to disable drag and drop of children of one parent to other parents.

Is there an easy and elegant way to do it ? Otherwise, I am thinking of using onNodeDrop and onNodeOver events.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery-ui .sortable() http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Calling .sortable() without connecting lists will allow you to sort items only within their parent.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot use jQuery since my tree is bound to the GeoExt library. I absolutely need to use Trees from ExtJS.

Comment: actually you could use the two together since they have separate namespaces, and you could integrate the GeoExt callback inside a closure for the sortable callback.

Comment: but otherwise I'd go with the onNodeDrop event, and if you want feedback for "you can't drop here" or "you can drop here" use the onNodeOver event.  I wrote my own drag and drop library from scratch a few weeks ago to deal with a tree situation that jQuery-ui couldn't handle, and cross browser using only native js it still was only around 200 lines, and since you've got custom events you can make use of it will probably be even easier